# Javascript menu icon to rotate 90 Degrees Onclick and rotate 90 degrees on second click

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, rotation, transform

I am looking to rotate my menu icon 90 degrees onclick and 90 degrees when a user click a second time.

I am using one function in Javascript and would like to know how to get it to rotate an additional 90 degrees when a user clicks the second time.

```
function spin(){

    var spin1 = document.getElementById("spin");
        spin2 = document.getElementById("spin");

    spin1.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";

}
```

Comment: if you use jQuery you can just use a toggleClass. I've made it in this codepen : http://codepen.io/mbrillaud/pen/XJZGgj Edit: oops, I didn't see the Android tag, i don't know how it works.

Comment: My task was to not use a Jquery library as the application in question is being styled and designed in pure Javascript. But thanks for the heads up and I will follow your code pen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below function

```
var click =false
function spin(){
        var spin1 = document.getElementById("spin");
        var spin2 = document.getElementById("spin");
    if(!click){
        spin1.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
        click=true;
       }else{
        click=false;
        spin1.style.transform = "rotate(180deg)";
       }
}
```

Comment: This code works perfectly but only once, do you know of a way to toggle this so that it will repeat every time the menu icon is clicked? Would I need to add variables to identify spin1 and spin2. have only been doing Javascript for a day or so

Comment: I have updated code for reversing it. But am not able to unserstand. you want it to called for both this function. Then call spin function onClick="spin(this)" and get value of transformed with "this" and get amount. If it's 90 then transform 180 else 90.

Comment: I have edited the code provided by Leonardo C, and have managed to get it to work. I have made a simple menu icon that rotate from a + to an x once it is clicked and then in reverse once clicked again.

Comment: Is it working for both ? spin1 and spin2.
And are you making a phonegap App?

Comment: It works for both clicks on and repeats every time. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var angle = 0;
function spin(){
    var spin1 = document.getElementById("spin");
    spin2 = document.getElementById("spin");
    angle+=90;
    spin1.style.transform = "rotate("+angle+"deg)";
}
```

This will let it rotate by 90 degrees every time it's pressed. If you want to limit to 2 :

```
var flag = false;
function spin(){
    var spin1 = document.getElementById("spin");
    spin2 = document.getElementById("spin");
    spin1.style.transform = "rotate("+(flag?180:90)+"deg)";
    flag = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The first code works perfectly and I have edited it slightly to allow it to work on Android.